# How should I configure CART for easier interpretation?

Tags: interpretation, cart

My goal is not to get better accuracy, but to make interpretation easier and have more stable splits.

So far most useful is use larger min_samples_leaf, but I always get nodes size almost same as min_samples_leaf.

Also I tried to cut input into interesting regions and run another tree in the subset.

Comment: If some variable is used only to split a few nodes out near the leaves,  you might try eliminating it from your analysis.